# Is Jmeter HttpRequest java implementation single threaded

Tags: jmeter

Looked at documentation at jmeter saying java implementation of http request.

The API is best suited to single-threaded usage - various settings (e.g. proxy) are defined via system properties, and therefore apply to all connections.

This statement is confusing. Does this mean if you put 100 threads in ThreadGroup, you only have actually one java thread? Just one thread to multiple connections? Or it means something else.

I thought Jmeter is to creating multiple java threads for stress testing. We want to take advantage of multiple processors with multiple java threads for stress testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean if you put 100 threads in ThreadGroup, you only have actually one java thread?

No, but I agree it's confusing. 100 threads means up to 100 concurrent connections.

The documentation says that since the Java HTTP API is configured through system properties, it works best with single-threaded applications. In multi-threaded environment it's hard to apply settings to only a single thread only because system properties are global.

HTTPClient sampler (which you should prefer) doesn't have such limitations since everything is configured explicitly and on a connection basis.

Comment: I understand 100 thread means up to 100 concurrent connections? But just want to confirm if 100 threads means 100 active java threads? Also can you explain more about why this is best single-threaded applications? As I know most sevlet container is multiple threaded, what is the usecase of this implementation, and it is weird to make it as the default configuration

Comment: @ShaozhenDing: yes, 100 threads means 100 Java threads, each starting a new HTTP connection. Once again, HTTP Java API is completely fine to run in multi-threaded applications, there is nothing wrong with it! It's just that it uses system-wide configuration, so it's harder to have fine-grained configuration on a per-thread basis.